# Complex integration using singularities

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

I'm working on Ablowitz and Fokas' Complex Variables. On section 3.5 on singularities, problem 2 reads:

Evaluate the integral of f(z) over the unit circle centered at the origin:

a) $f(z)=z/(z^2 + w^2)$

b) $f(z)=1/(8z^3+1)$

Normally, I would proceed with finding the residue, but for a) I do not know how to handle the $w^2$ term once I break the function down to geometric series. If $|w|>1$ , it seems to me that the function is analytic since z is not equal to w for any z on the unit circle, so the integral just vanishes.

For b) the expression I get by partial fractions is too complicated, and I'm suspecting that the point of this exercise is not to manipulate series since it is a chapter on singularities.

Is there a smarter way to evaluate these integrals if I have information about their singularities? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Cauchy's Residue Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem

Comment: I don't mean to sound unappreciative, but very prominently positioned in my question you can find the sentence "Normally, I would proceed with finding the residue, but...".                                                       
I'm looking forward to any less perfunctory hints or answers!

Comment: And moreover, the calculus of residues isn't treated until the next chapter... Can't you simply use antiderivatives, rather than series expansions?

Comment: Sorry, I read your question incorrectly by forgetting your initial sentence after reading the last, which lead my thoughts down the wrong path !

Comment: That's not a problem. If you decompose into partial fractions, each term gives a logarithm, which you can define with a suitable branch cut, and then you integrate around the circle, starting on one side of the cut and ending up at "almost the same point" but on the opposite side of the cut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out, I can factor $z^2$ out of the denominator in a) and $8z^3$ in b) and that gets me the geometric series I want to find the residue.

At first, I blindly began with partial fractions and ended up with a mess, and I figured it is pretty unlikely they are asking for something that technically painstaking in a section that does not even focus on integration, but turns out it was just another routine geometric series.

Note: @pbs was correct, both times! (I got Mathematica to solve them in polar coordinates and got the correct result).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cauchy's Integral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) which gives that the area over a holomorphic (i.e. complex analytic) function is exactly zero if the closed contour contains no singularities.

Or you could evaluate the following way just to convince yourself: The unit circle is $z=e^{i\theta}$ where $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$, so we have: $dz=ie^{i\theta}d\theta$.
So, for (a) we get
$$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{z}{z^2+w^2} = \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{ie^{2i\theta}}{e^{2i\theta}+w^2}d\theta=\cdots$$

**NOTE** When you come to do the residue theorem later on, you will see that it generalises the integral theorem to allow for singularities within the closed contour of integration. Basically we just sum up the residues at the singularities and multiply by $2\pi i$. Easy as $2\pi i$ !

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Now, I am familiar with Cauchy's integral theorem, but for all w such that |w|=1, I would have a singularity in my contour, and cannot use the theorem, that's why I was wondering if they simply want me to mention that I can solve this for |w|>1.

Note: this section is after a discussion on the residue theorem, and they have already posed a lot of problems requiring the residue theorem, that's why I'm suspecting that for a section on singularities they are looking for something different.

Comment: Yes, you can only use the theorem if its conditions are met, so any restrictions are perfectly acceptable. Later on you will be able to state the correct value of the integral for your special case ($|w|=1$) once you know how to compute it using the residue theorem. I suspect your lecturer will not expect you to consider the special case, but if you do know how to use the residue theorem then just evaluate that special case as well and put that in your answer ! Make sure to follow the instructions of the question carefully though - maybe they don't want you to consider that special case...